# find $(p+q)^3$ when $\sec x - \tan x = 2$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question.

> Let $x$ be a real number such that $\sec x - \tan x = 2$ If the value of $\sec x + \tan x=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are integers, find $(p+q)^3$

What I have tried so far:

Taking the equation:

$\sec x - \tan x = 2$
$\tan x+2=\sec x$

Now substituting that into $\sec x + \tan x=\frac{p}{q}$
$\tan x+2 + \tan x=\frac{p}{q}$
$= 2\tan x + 2=\frac{p}{q}$
So $2\tan x=\frac{p}{q}-\frac{2q}{q}$
$= 2\tan x=\frac{p-2q}{q}$

I am not sure about this. How can I simplify it further to find the values of $p$ and $q$

Comment: $$
1 = \sec ^2 x - \tan ^2 x= (\sec x - \tan x)(\sec x + \tan x) = 2\frac{p}{q} \Rightarrow q = 2p
$$ may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://brainly.in/question/3351681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $\sec^2x-\tan^2x=1$ to find the the value of $\sec x+\tan x$. Then, you can easily find $(p+q)^3$.

Comment: So then $secx+tanx$ will be $\frac{1}{secx-tanx}$ which is $\frac{1}{2}$ and then substitute that, which means $p=1,q=2$

Comment: Thank a lot. It was a useful hint!

Comment: @sujay This does not mean $p=1,q=2$, for example $p=2,q=4$ works.

Comment: @Asher2211, Yep, all multiples of $\frac{1}{2}$ work

Comment: @Sujay So you can't find the exact value of $(p+q)^3$